# Resource Limit reached woocommerce eprocessing network payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have bought a woocommerce plugin that allows to receive payments from clients in my ecommerce store.

when users try to pay , they see an error "Resource Limit Error" .

I tried to re-install and re-configured but the problem remains.

I have also checked the error log file in my cPanel but could not find any error.

Checked my bandwidth information. It says I used 1% of my allowcation.

Your help is appreciated .

Comment: First of all, is there a live version where we can see this happen? And the name of this plugin? (Posting a support ticket there too could perhaps help).